# HTTP 400 Bad Request when using getfilebyserverrelativeurl or getfolderbyserverrelativeurl

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have been trying to setup a basic CRUD operations sample SharePoint 2013 App.

I have a developer template site setup (e.g. reporting.domain.com/sites/dev). Inside that site I have a "Document Library" app/list setup with a file. I have given "web" write permissions in the manifest.

What I need is to do the basic CRUD operations via the REST API. Right now I am just trying the get and delete operations.  I get a 400 "Bad Request" back. I am totally stuck. Ideas?

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<m:error xmlns:m=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata\">
<m:code>-2147024809, System.ArgumentException</m:code>
<m:message xml:lang=\"en-US\">Value does not fall within the expected range.</m:message>
</m:error>
```

Here is the javascript code I am using. gethostWebTitleAndCreated works but neither getReport or deleteReport work

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var hostweburl,
        appweburl;

    // Function to retrieve a query string value.
    // For production purposes you may want to use
    //  a library to handle the query string.
    function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
        var params, i, singleParam;
        params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");

        for (i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
            singleParam = params[i].split("=");
            if (singleParam[0] === paramToRetrieve) {
                return singleParam[1];
            }
        }
    }

    function gethostWebTitleAndCreated() {
        var url = appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web?@target='" + hostweburl + "'" + "&$select=title,created";
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: url,
                type: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "contentType": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("<p>", {
                        text: data.d.Title
                    }).appendTo("#output");

                },
                error: function (err) {
                    $("<p>", {
                        text: JSON.stringify(err)
                    }).appendTo("#output");
                }

            }
        );
    }

    function deleteReport() {
        var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
        executor.executeAsync({
            url: "../_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web" +
                "/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/Custom Reports/NewReport.rdlx')" +
                "?@target='" + hostweburl + "'",
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "X-HTTP-Method": "DELETE",
                "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "IF-MATCH": "*"
            },
            success: function () {
                alert("Hurray!");
            },
            error: function (err) {
                $("<p>", {
                    text: JSON.stringify(err)
                }).appendTo("#output");
            }
        });
    }

    function getReport() {
        var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
        executor.executeAsync({
            url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web" +
                "/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/Custom Reports/NewReport.rdlx')/$value" +
                "?@target='" + hostweburl + "'",
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "contentType": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function () {
                alert("Hurray!");
            },
            error: function (err) {
                $("<p>", {
                    text: JSON.stringify(err)
                }).appendTo("#output");
            }
        });
    }



    // Load the required SharePoint libraries
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Get the URI decoded URLs.
        hostweburl =
            decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
        appweburl =
            decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));

        // resources are in URLs in the form:
        // web_url/_layouts/15/resource
        var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";

        // Load the js files and continue to the successHandler
        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", gethostWebTitleAndCreated);
        $("#getreport").on("click", getReport);
        $("#deletereport").on("click", deleteReport);


    });
}());
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error for endpoint `http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl(serverRelativeUrl)`:

```
Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

occurs when the file specified by `serverRelativeUrl` parameter could not be found.

Make sure the `serverRelativeUrl` parameter for a file is specified correctly, the following format is used:

```
/<web>/<list>/<folder>/<file>
```

Comment: Thanks. This blew my mind a bit since in EVERY one of the Microsoft documents it always shows the path as /folder/file.

Comment: Unfortunately you are not alone, i also was surprised when discovered that parameter have to include web url..

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my case I was using directly folder name instead of '/sites/' prefix. Now it worked.

Answer (score 8):

Another workaround (which I was also surprised to discover) is to **remove the leading `/` character**.

### Not working

```
http://site url/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared Documents')
```

### Working

```
http://site url/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared Documents')
```

Comment: This works for GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl, but not for getFileByServerRelativeUrl. Microsoft logic...